# Teradata dynamic SELECT

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to make a dynamic query on all the tables in a database.

I would like to be able to execute a select to list all the tables of the bbdd:

```
SELECT  TABLENAME
FROM    DBC.TABLESV
WHERE   TABLEKIND = 'T' AND DATABASENAME = 'MyDatabase'
```

And then make a select in each of the existing tables in this list.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: The only way I know of to do  dynamic SQL in Teradata is in a stored procedure. There's tons of info out there about this.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have permissions to create stored procedure

Comment: Run `SELECT  'select * from ' || databasename || '.' TABLENAME || ';' FROM...`, cut&paste the result and run it. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: @dnoeth I need to control the operations movements for each table. In each table I have type of operation and date. In this way I want to see if a table has many variations or few. Can you explain your idea a little more?

Comment: You need to create those Selects dynamically, i.e. the result of the query is a list of Selects. Then you run those Selects, in SQL Assistant/Studio you copy the result to the query window, in BTEQ you export the result to a file and then `.run file...`.

Comment: I wish I could get the results in a single query but I don't see the way